# What is the right way to importing a skeletal mesh from Unreal to Blender?

Tags: rigging, unreal-engine

I tried exporting a skeletal mesh as an FBX file from Unreal with default settings, then importing it in Blender.  But the bones are disordered even if "Automatic Bone Orientation" is checked.  I looking for a solution and took one day no right result (e.g.  Better FBX Importer & Exporter, UEFY2) on internet!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered that the skeleton imported into Blender from Unreal, while looking wrong, was not quite. You can binding skin, painting weight and animating with the “wrong” skeleton, and finally successfully import into Unreal.